# Problem with algebra formulas for work with gdal_calc.py

Tags: raster, gdal, raster-calculator, map-algebra, gdal-calc

I'm trying to update some values of a raster based on another raster.

1st raster (A): landuse data (values from 10 to 240)

2nd raster (B): mask data (only nodata values and a given value, for example: 20)

Objective: for a given pixel, if Pixel A == 212 and Pixel B == 20, replace pixel A with pixel B value.

So, my 1st command is: `B*(A==212)`. That works fine, I'm getting a raster with pixels that matches the objectives and with the new value.

I'm having problems with the second raster manipulation. I dont know how to get a new full raster with values updated.

Anyone have an idea of how I can do that in, if possible, only one math formula ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the test yields either 1 (true) or 0 (false). So you can make an "and" by multiplying the results, and the othe cases using 1-(condition). Here ismy suggestion

```
B*(A==212)*(B==20) + A*(1-(A==212)*(B==20))
```